# Widget actions based on stream data

Tags: dart, flutter

I come across this situation
I have a controller class that holds a stream with asynchronous data

```
class Controller {
    Stream stream;
}
```

I need the widgets of my application to be able to do certain actions when i get certain data from the stream. 
for example, i have a widget that needs to get a specific message from the stream to move on to a different page.

What would be the best way in which i could share the stream with multiple widgets? making the stream static (global) is probably a poor solution

Comment: You can use StreamBuilder - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: inheritedwidget + broadcaststream

Comment: For an example of what @RémiRousselet is saying, you can look at the [flutter_redux](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/blob/master/lib/flutter_redux.dart) source code which uses the stream from the [store](https://github.com/johnpryan/redux.dart/blob/master/lib/src/store.dart) to trigger updates.